# error= ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'

Tags: python, scipy

```
#ImportError: cannot import name 'comb'

import scipy
from scipy.misc import comb

# Loading the vectorizer and classfier
with open('classifier.pickle','rb') as f:
classifier = pickle.load(f)

with open('tfidfmodel.pickle','rb') as f:
vectorizer = pickle.load(f)
```

both the files classifier.pickle and tfid.pickle as kept in same folder

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.comb.html: "comb is deprecated! Importing comb from scipy.misc is deprecated in scipy 1.0.0. Use **scipy.special.comb** instead."

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question? If so, please mark it as "accepted" (with the little green V mark), so that others will know that the question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the location of `classifier` or `vectorizer` (`tfid` does not appear in your question).
This is an import error, due to the fact that [`comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html) was moved to `scipy.special`. This would've been easy to find by googling "scipy.misc.comb" and seeing the result "scipy.special.comb" fairly high.